# Herbie Hancock solo on Witch Hunt

Tags: piano, jazz

In Herbie Hancock's solo on Witch Hunt, these two measures feature descending perfect 4th triplets. Is that why this excerpt of the solo sounds so pleasant? And what scales does he use over the Emaj7 and Eb7 chords?

[image]

Comment: The chromatic scale.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like the rhythm and the pitch sequence are two independent things. The descending line starting from the second beat of the first bar has note pairs where the lower note steps along a wholetone scale, and the upper note stays at a perfect fourth distance, thus stepping along the other wholetone scale. And finally there's a step of only a single semitone, which might work for returning the "outside" wandering run back to the key.

Here are two variations of a somewhat similar run:

[image: wholetone and perfect fourths]

The triplet rhythm could be anything, it's like arpeggiating chords. Pick a rhythm you like.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for asking such an interesting question (actually 2 questions). I’d like to point out that the Eb7(9)(13) actually falls on beat 3 (or syncopated on the 2+) of the previous bar, not the downbeat of the second bar. However in Herbie’s solo the first chorus he doesn’t play the second chord and on the second chorus he does play one bar each.

You’ve identified this as what it is, a series of descending 4ths. It starts on the 16th notes of bar 1, beat 2 in whole steps with just one chromatic step from Cb-Fb to Bb-Eb. To be clear the last 2 are Ab-Db, from the key signature and a previous accidental. The 3 chromatic notes on bar 1, beat 1 actually sound like 4, I hear a slightly ghosted E on the 4th 16th note of best 1 (I slowed it down in my DAW to be sure). This makes sense as it leads chromatically into the beginning of the 4ths figure.

One interesting thing to point out is by playing descending 4ths stepwise you are in effect playing a 12 tone row or all the notes of the cycle of 5ths.

Now to your questions, why does it sound so pleasant? This question is highly subjective but for those of us with a modern jazz sensibility the sound and nature of 4ths is very appealing. Another aspect is the “in and out” factor. Beat 2 starts very inside the changes, 7,3,6,9 over the Emaj9 then goes out on the Eb9, B,E,A,D then gradually and naturally works its way back in, G,C,F,Bb but never really completely, which is the nature of a cycle or chromatic over a chord change. The pattern is given preference over playing “correct notes” over the chord.

As for your second question, Herbie takes just 2 choruses and in effect there are only 2 bars with Emaj9 in each chorus so there’s not enough of a reference as far as a scale but aside from playing Lydian (typical for that era) he seems to also like playing the #1, so an F locrian or (F# major scale) over Emaj9. The Eb9 chords are played for the most part as Lydian dominants and you can hear this clearly on the Eb9 chords in bars 9-12 of the form. On the second chorus he does play a b13 to lead to the Abm7 chord. Here is a transcription of those same 2 bars the second time:

[image]